# Remove bounding box from metadata view in Geonetwork

Tags: html, metadata, geonetwork, gui

I want to remove the spatial extent (bounding box) section from all the metadata views because all I can see with my uploaded data is this:

[image]

I tried to edit the 'catalog/views/default/templates/recordView.html' file by commenting the spatial extent section, but it didn't work and I can't figure out how the metadata views works. I guess that Angular has something to do with it, but I don't know how to edit the scripts in order to remove this section from the metadata views. I've read [the docs](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.10.x/en/customizing-application/creating-custom-view.html), but I couldn't reach any conclusion about how to do it.

*Edited to add a more descriptive screenshot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have extents, so the map should work; possibly a bug.